# isset on static class attributes

Tags: php, oop, static, static-members, isset

```
class A {
    public static $foo = 42;
}

$class = 'A';
$attribute = 'foo';

var_dump(isset($class::$attribute)); //gives bool(false)
```

How can i checkt, of this static attribute exists in this class?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in question titles.

Comment: @Tomala Geret'kal: ok, next time i'll do it right :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
var_dump(isset($class::$$attribute)); // the two dollars are intentional
```

If you don't have PHP 5.3 yet the only accurate way is probably using the [Reflection API](http://php.net/Reflection):

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
$exists = $reflectionClass->hasProperty($attribute) && $reflectionClass->getProperty($attribute)->isStatic();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works :) I accept you answer as soon as I can (12 minutes left) :)

Comment: Wow, variable variables can get confusing quick.

Comment: @JohnP: Probably you are using an older PHP version. The `$class::` syntax was introduced in PHP 5.3.

Comment: @nikic: How can i do this for PHP < 5.3? I want have as much compability to older versions as possible.

Comment: @nikic ahhh, that's it. I haven't migrated to 5.3 yet. Was just about to -1 you after running it on codepad to verify. Apparently they haven't migrated yet either ^_^

Comment: I'm still waiting for 5.4 when you can also write `$$class::$$attribute`.

Comment: I think that `property_exists($class, $attribute)` is clearer, though it won't distinguish between static and non-static members, and it only works on non-public members as of 5.3.

Comment: @mario: Just checked trunk and the part before `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` is still only `class_name` or `reference_variable`. `$$class` would need at least a `variable_without_objects` ;)

Comment: `get_class_vars` might be useful.

Comment: @levu: I added a possibility using Reflection ;)

Answer (score 1):

In 5.3, you can simply do

```
var_dump(property_exists($class, $attribute));
```

Comment: property_exists('class','attribute') to clarify this answer