# How to know if static property is inherited in php?

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, static

I have a `$class_name = 'B';`

And :

```
class A
{
    static $foo = 42;
    static $baz = 4;
}

class B extends A
{
   static $bar = 2;
   static $baz = 44;
}
```

How can I know if `$class_name::$foo` is a static property for the $class_name or if it's a inherited static property?

I need following result :

```
$class_name = 'A';
isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'foo'); //TRUE : is a static property of this class

$class_name = 'B';
isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'foo'); //FALSE : is NOT a static property of this class

$class_name = 'B';
isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'bar'); //TRUE : is a static property of this class

$class_name = 'A';
isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'bar'); //FALSE : is NOT a static property of this class

$class_name = 'B';
isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'baz'); //TRUE : is a static property of this class

$class_name = 'A';
isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'baz'); //TRUE : is a static property of this class
```

How implement `isOwnStaticProperty()` function?

Comment: You can check `get_parent_class` at http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php

Comment: yes, but after? how check if it's property of class or parent class?

Comment: I update my answer with your las update, check the code I will write the explanation now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) with the method [getProperties](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) to retrieves the reflected properties. To filter you can use [ReflectionProperty](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php)

```
<?php

class A
{
    static $foo = 42;
    static $baz = 4;
}

class B extends A
{
   static $bar = 2;
   static $baz = 44;
}

function isOwnStaticProperty($class, $prop) {
    $reflect = new ReflectionClass($class);
    //Filtering only the statics values with ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC
    $props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC);
    foreach ($props as $object) {
        if($object->class == $class && $object->name == $prop) {
            return true;
        }    
    }
    return false;
}   


$class_name = 'A';
echo isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'foo') ? "TRUE<br>\n" : "FALSE<br>\n"; 

$class_name = 'B';
echo isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'foo') ? "TRUE<br>\n" : "FALSE<br>\n"; 

$class_name = 'B';
echo isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'bar') ? "TRUE<br>\n" : "FALSE<br>\n"; 

$class_name = 'A';
echo isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'bar') ? "TRUE<br>\n" : "FALSE<br>\n"; 

$class_name = 'B';
echo isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'baz') ? "TRUE<br>\n" : "FALSE<br>\n"; 

$class_name = 'A';
echo isOwnStaticProperty($class_name, 'baz') ? "TRUE<br>\n" : "FALSE<br>\n";
```

OUTPUT:

> TRUE
>  
>   FALSE
>   TRUE
>   FALSE
>   TRUE
>  
>   TRUE

Comment: It also works with non static properties which should be noted, it might be not intended in his case

Comment: @insanebits yes I see, I will update now, is just a verification

Comment: and what about directly use http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getstaticproperties.php ?

Comment: @insanebits I update my answer, with the filter for only static properties

Comment: @Matrix if you use getStaticProperties you will get the inherits properties without his class, test the example in the manual

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer now function does what it says, nice :)

Comment: Ok, your filter as look fine, I will test this, thx^^ EDIT : It's rock, well answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

#### Edit: This answer is valid only for revision #1 of the question, when the parent class contains no property by the same name.

Use [`get_parent_class`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php) in combination with [`isset` and variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771808/2302862):

```
function isOwnStaticProperty($class, $property)
{
    $parent = get_parent_class($class);
    return isset($class::$$property) && ($parent === FALSE || !isset($parent::$$property));
}
```

This checks whether `$class` has a static property named `$property`, and either has no parent class, or the parent class does not have such a property.

Note the two `$` before `property` in `isOwnStaticProperty`.

Call it like

```
echo isOwnStaticProperty('A', 'foo'); // TRUE
echo isOwnStaticProperty('A', 'bar'); // FALSE
echo isOwnStaticProperty('B', 'foo'); // FALSE
echo isOwnStaticProperty('B', 'bar'); // TRUE
```

Comment: there is a case where not work. it's my fault I don't present this case in my exemple, I EDIT question. In case where static property is defined in parent AND in current class

Comment: Don't you have to go all the way back to the "root" class (i.e. the first class that does not extend anything) to properly know if the static variable is inherited? It should be pretty easy to make the function recursive.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen If any class in the inheritance chain contains a property, every inheriting class will, including the direct parent of the class in question. Therefore, if the immediate parent does not contain it, no class up the chain contains it.